How can i find rebased commits in remote git repo
Now, i am trying to find rebased commits in remote git repo using Python.
I used Github api to find it.
The repository is huge, there are many contributors and branches.
In certain branch, finding new commits is not problem.
but i can't identify which commits are newly submitted at that branch, and which commits are rebased from other branch.
If anyone know about it, please help me

git-cherry(1) and search for “cherry” in man git log. That’s all that can be said for such a general question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

about "more details": you say you intend to use Github API: do you run your commands from within a clone of that repo ? (<- in that case, you can also use regular git commands) or do you have a hard constraint to go exclusively through Github API ?

someone may correct me, but I don't know of a reliable way to query "is that commit a cherry-pick of that other commit ?" through Github API. On a local git clone: you can compute and compare git patch-id for two commits. git cherry and git log --cherry-* (as suggested by @Guildenstern) use this under the hood and will give you more synthetic informations.

i posted my code bellow, i have to define is_rebased func for identify which commits are newly submitted at that branch directly, and which commits are rebased from other branch

def compare_states(current_state, previous_state):
new_branches = []
updated_branches = []
deleted_branches = []
rebased_commits = []

# Set of branch keys (repo_owner, repo_name, branch_name) for the current state
current_branch_keys = {(b['repo_owner'], b['repo_name'], b['branch_name']) for b in current_state}

for current_branch in current_state:
    repo_full_name = f"{current_branch['repo_owner']}/{current_branch['repo_name']}"
    repo = g.get_repo(repo_full_name)
    
    # Find the corresponding branch in the previous state
    previous_branch = next((b for b in previous_state 
                            if b["repo_owner"] == current_branch["repo_owner"] 
                            and b["repo_name"] == current_branch["repo_name"] 
                            and b["branch_name"] == current_branch["branch_name"]), None)
    
    # Case 1: New Branch
    if previous_branch is None:
        # Check against the default branch to detect new branches
        parent_branch = find_parent_branch(repo, current_branch)  # Implement this to find the parent
        comparison = repo.compare(parent_branch, current_branch["branch_name"])
        
        # If commits exist in the comparison, it's a new branch
        if comparison.commits:
            new_branches.append({
                "repo_owner": current_branch["repo_owner"],
                "repo_name": current_branch["repo_name"],
                "branch_name": current_branch["branch_name"],
                "commit_hash": current_branch["commit_hash"],
                "commits": convert_commits(comparison.commits)
            })
    
    # Case 2: Updated or Rebasing Branch
    else:
        # Compare the current and previous commit hashes to detect changes
        if current_branch["commit_hash"] != previous_branch["commit_hash"]:
            comparison = repo.compare(previous_branch["commit_hash"], current_branch["commit_hash"])
            updated_commits = convert_commits(comparison.commits)
            # Case 2a: Rebasing branch
            for commit in updated_commits:
                if is_rebased(commit["sha"], repo_full_name):
                    rebased_commits.append(commit)
            # Case 2b: Regular update (but not rebased)
            else:
                updated_branches.append({
                    "repo_owner": current_branch["repo_owner"],
                    "repo_name": current_branch["repo_name"],
                    "branch_name": current_branch["branch_name"],
                    "current_commit_hash": current_branch["commit_hash"],
                    "previous_commit_hash": previous_branch["commit_hash"],
                    "commits": updated_commits
                })

# Case 3: Deleted Branches
for previous_branch in previous_state:
    # If a branch in previous_state is not in current_state, it's deleted
    if (previous_branch['repo_owner'], previous_branch['repo_name'], previous_branch['branch_name']) not in current_branch_keys:
        deleted_branches.append(previous_branch)

# Return the results as 4 separate lists: new, updated, deleted, and rebased branches
return new_branches, updated_branches, deleted_branches, rebased_commits

Determines if a branch has been rebased by checking the base commit SHA.
def is_rebased(commit_sha, repo_full_name):
pass  # Implement the logic here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
